# Suppose $\int |t|dG_i(t)<\infty,$ show that $\int |G_1(t)-G_2(t)|^pdt<\infty$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose $G_1$ and $G_2$ are two c.d.f.'s on $\mathbb{R}$, and 
$\int |t|dG_i(t)<\infty,~ i=1,2.$

Show that $\int |G_1(t)-G_2(t)|^pdt<\infty$ for $p\ge1$.

I have no idea of this problem. Can anybody give some suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X_i$ be r.v.'s with c.d.f.'s $G_i$. Since the expectations $\mathbb EX_i$ exists, i.e. 
$$\mathbb E[|X_i|]=\int_{-\infty}^\infty |t|dG_i(t)<\infty,$$
then the following integrals are finite:
$$\tag{1}\label{1}
\mathbb E[X_i^+] = \int_0^\infty (1-G_i(t))\,dt<\infty, \quad \mathbb E [X_i^-]=\int_{-\infty}^0 G_i(t) dt<\infty
$$
Here $X_i^+=\max(X_i,0)$, $X_i^-=-\min(X_i,0)\geq 0$ are positive and negative parts of $X_i$. Remind that 
$$
\mathbb E[X_i] = \mathbb E[X_i^+] - \mathbb E [X_i^-] = \int_0^\infty (1-G_i(t))\,dt - \int_{-\infty}^0 G_i(t) dt.$$

To prove that 
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty |G_1(t)-G_2(t)|^pdt<\infty  \text{ for } p\geq 1,
$$
use  [Minkowski inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality). First split the integral:
$$\tag{2}\label{2}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty |G_1(t)-G_2(t)|^p dt =\int_{-\infty}^0 |G_1(t)-G_2(t)|^p dt + \int_{0}^\infty \bigl|\bigl(1-G_1(t)\bigr)-\bigl(1-G_2(t)\bigr)\bigr|^p dt. 
$$
Next apply Minkowski inequality to both parts. 
$$
\left(\int_{-\infty}^0 |G_1(t)-G_2(t)|^p dt\right)^{1/p}\leq 
\left(\int_{-\infty}^0 (G_1(t))^p dt \right)^{1/p}+\left(\int_{-\infty}^0 (G_2(t))^p dt \right)^{1/p}.
$$
But $(G_i(t))^p\leq G_i(t)$ for $p\geq 1$ since $0\leq G_i(t)\leq 1$. Then by (\ref{1})
$$
\left(\int_{-\infty}^0 |G_1(t)-G_2(t)|^p dt\right)^{1/p}\leq 
\left(\int_{-\infty}^0 G_1(t)) dt \right)^{1/p}+\left(\int_{-\infty}^0 G_2(t)) dt \right)^{1/p}<\infty.
$$
and the first summand in r.h.s. of (\ref{2}) is finite.

The same way prove that the second summand in  r.h.s. of (\ref{2}) is finite too.